# How can I generate a stubs file for Joomla?

Tags: php, development, development-tool

I'd like to develop Joomla components with VS Code.
With [PHP Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) enabled, all my file show errors because I use Joomla classes and functions. (And it would also be convenient to have auto complete for Joomla functions)

To solve the same problem with WordPress, one can just add `wordpress` to the `intelephense.stubs` array in the settings. Unfortunately there are no stubs for Joomla, but it is possible to add your own stub files.

Is there a way to generate a stubs file for Joomla, or does it already exist and can be downloaded?

### Additional remark

I develop the extension in a separate directory, so I have all of the files in one place and the editor and git is not cluttered with the Joomla files. Therefore the editor doesn't see the Joomla classes and functions.
The setting `intelephense.environment.includePaths` seems to be a solution for this issue.
But I'm still wondering if there is a way to do via the stubs approach (the way it's solved for WordPress), so I don't have to add the `includePaths` for every project.

### Update

Running `build/stubGenerator.php` script results in this error (on Linux)

```
Error: Failed to start application: Class Joomla\CMS\Filesystem\Support\StringController does not exist%
```

If I change the file name of `./joomla-cms-staging/libraries/src/Filesystem/Support/Stringcontroller.php` to `StringController.php`, the script finishes without an error. But the generated file (`stubs.php`) doesn't appear to be complete (at least to me). Every entry looks like this (total of 1877 lines):

```
/**
 * @deprecated 5.0 Use Joomla\... instead.
 */
class ... extends Joomla\... {}
```

Answer (score 1):

When running Joomla from git clone you can use `build/stubGenerator.php` script. It will generate `stubs.php` file in Joomla's root directory.

Comment: I tried that, but I get an error. See update in question.

Comment: This is a known issue caused by incorrectly cased file. It hasn't been fixed in core yet. As a workaround you can rename `Stringcontroller.php` in `libraries/src/Filesystem/Support` to `StringController.php`.

Comment: I already did that, but there are only `@deprecated` classes (375 of them) in the `stubs.php` file (more details in the question update). I'm not sure but it doesn't feel like that is what it should be, is it?

Comment: Yes, that's what the script does. Other classes should be picked up automatically by your editor.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have been more clear. I develop my extension in a separate directory, the Joomla installation is in a different location and the editor doesn't have access to it. I found the setting `intelephense.environment.includePaths` yesterday, that seems to solve the problem. But I'm still wondering if there is a similar approach than there is for WordPress, for which you just add stubs.

Comment: @jost21 Please, could you share your knowledge on how you set the intelephense.environment.includePaths to get rid of the file errors?

Comment: @cappu check the setting of the extension, there you will can set up the intelephense.environment.includePaths with the path to the root of a joomla folder. Or better, in your workspace add the `"intelephense.environment.includePaths": ["/path/to/joomla/folder"]` to the .json settings and done

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why a `intelephense.environment.includePaths` is not useful for you, even when you can have a git clone of joomla in your environment, keep up to date (even you can change of branch for handle different versions) and point to there any new workspace folder you working on. You can set up globally, in this way any new workspace will have it, but is better have all this settings for each workspace in my opinion - this if you do not work only with Joomla.

About `intelephense.stubs` For single workspace it is very simple, and I follow the same I wrote before about having a git clone of joomla.
If you want add stubs globally, you still can, but I'm not sure if it's intended feature with custom stubs.

About the error you mention, I just rebuild again in Linux/Ubuntu and without problem

Comment: `intelephense.environment.includePaths` is useful to me :), I like mentioned that's what I currently use. I'm just wondering if there is a similar way to the wordpress approach (set `intelephense.stubs` to `wordpress` or adding custom stubs for Joomla).